# Rewrite to HTTPS with subdomain?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

How can I setup web.config to handle the following redirects

1. `http://example.com`     -> `https://example.sub.com`
2. `http://www.example.com` -> `https://example.sub.com`
3. `http://example.sub.com` -> `https://example.sub.com`

The part I am not sure about is matching the urls, for example,

`http://<dynamic>` to `http://<dynamic>.sub.com`

Comment: You might get some ideas from Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with two rules.  One will match when the hostname contains .sub.com and simply perform a plain redirect.  The next will append .sub.com to the hostname.

These are based off #4 of https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#redirect-https

Finally, after you've proved that everything works as expected, changed the Found to Permanent in both rules.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="(.*)" />  
    <conditions>  
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />  
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.sub\.com$" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />  
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="(.*)" />  
    <conditions>  
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />    
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}.sub.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"     />  
</rule>
```